# what does the condition "\>" mean in an if statement in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hi I can't seem to find this anywhere. What does this forward slash> mean in an if statement in bash?

eg:

```
if [ "$count" \> 0 ]; then
echo hello
else
echo goodbye
fi
```

Comment: What coding language is this for? I *suspect* the ```\``` is an escape needed for another context outside of, and not related to, the actual language.

Comment: hi this is in bash.

Comment: When comparing numbers in a shell script, you'll usually want to use the `-gt`, `-lt`, `-le`, -ge`, `-ne`, or `-eq`

Comment: It's `[` syntax, not `if` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters `<` and `>` (among others) are special in shell scripts: they perform *input/output redirection*.  So when you're trying to use them in a test expression like this, with their "normal meaning" of "less than" and "greater than", you need to *escape* them, preventing them from being treated specially by the shell.

It's similar to the way you might write

```
cat file\ name
```

to cat a file with a space in its name, or

```
cat it\'s
```

to cat a file with a single quote character in its name.  (That is, normally, the space character is "special" in that it separates arguments, and the single quote character is special in that it quotes things, so to allow these characters to actually be used as part of a file name, you have to quote them, in this case using `\` to turn off their special meaning.)

Quoting ends up being complicated in the Unix/Linux shells, because there are typically *three* different quote characters: `"`, `'`, and `\`.  They all work differently, and the rules (while they mostly make sense) are complicated enough that I'm not going to repeat them here.

Another way to write this, avoiding the ugly quoting, would be

```
if [ "$count" -gt 0 ]
```

And it turns out this is preferable for another reason.  If you use `-gt`, it will do the comparison based on the *numeric* values of `$count` and `0`, which is presumably what you want here.  If you use `>` (that is, `\>`), on the other hand, it will perform a *string* comparison.  In this case, you'd probably get the same result, but in general, doing a string comparison when you meant to compare numerically can give crazy results.  See Charles Duffy's comment for an example.

Comment: `[ "$count" -gt 0 ]` and `[ "$count" \> 0 ]` do two different operations. `-gt` is a numeric comparison, `\>` is a string-sorting comparison -- they're not synonymous with each other.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did not know that.  (Until today I never realized test(1) accepted `<` and `>` at all.)  Thanks.  I'll fix.

Comment: To give a concrete example of when they have different results, compare `[ 3 \> 10 ]` with `[ 3 -gt 10 ]`. The former is true, because `3` has a higher ASCII ordinal than `1` and it compares character-by-character; the latter is false, because `3` is a smaller number than `10`.

Comment: (re: "never realized" -- `>` is a nonstandard extension, so it's not guaranteed to be present)

Comment: One of the nice things about using `[[` instead is that operators like `>` don't need to be escaped like this.

Answer (score 0):

- This `\>`means **GREATER THAN for STRINGS in ASCII ALPHABET**
- BASH has diferent meaning for **backslash** symbol `\`
- in your example `\>` is a symbol, not two things like `\` + `>`
- For numbers you use `>` BUT ALSO take in consideration the `[` `]` for arithmetic operations you would use `((` `))`
- A constructor in bash is with this symbol `[[` `]]` it's used to compare with these symbols inside double brackets

  - `&&, ||, <, and >`
  - IF YOU USE single brackets `[` `]` with  THE ABOVE symbols, YOU GET ERRORS IN BASH SCRIPT, you need the double brackets.

##### Other Meanings of BACKSLASH

- As mentioned before, in bash, you use forward slash `/` for PATH `/home/user/Desktop/file1.txt` but if your file NAME has spaces, you need to ESCAPE the blank space, and you do it with backslash `\`, example given

##### file name with spaces.txt

```
  /home/alex/Desktop/file\ name\ with\ spaces.txt
```

##### file name with symbols -> [Stackoverflow]fileName.txt

```
 /home/alex/Desktop/\[Stackoverflow\]fileName.txt
```

You need to escape each BRACKET `[` `]` LIKE this `\[` `\]`

### Resources

[Bash Constructors](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) |
[Bash operators](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/redirect-operators-bash) |
[Ascii Table](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/greater-than-sign-inequality-ascii-code-62.html)